# XAMPP - Unable to serve files larger than ~30MB

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm developing a site locally with XAMPP on Windows 7, and as far as media is concerned, I'm unable to play media files that are larger than 30MB or so. Both video and audio files (MP4 and MP3 respectively) generate this error in Chrome (and show similar errors in other browsers such as IE9 and Opera):

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

It seems that the exact number of MB somewhat varies between browsers though. One video in question is 34MB and actually plays in Opera and IE9, but gives the aforementioned error in Chrome.

I've checked to make sure the file paths were typed correctly and ensured that the directive for .htaccess is there to serve MP4s: `AddType video/mp4 mp4`

Also, I have these directives set as well in the same .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize "80M"
php_value post_max_size "80M"
php_value max_input_time 60
php_value max_execution_time 60
```

And `memory_limit` is set in php.ini as "128M" so I'm left wondering: what is causing my files to not play, and what, if any, directives I have to change on the server-side? Perhaps something to do with limitations with the GET method (the method I'm seeing on Chrome's network tab among other header request/response info)?

Comment: How are you serving these media files? Direct link? Through a PHP script? HTML5 `video` element?

Comment: In the end, through the HTML5 video element with flash fall-back. However, I have tried all those serving methods you mentioned to see what was going wrong. For the MP4s that are >30MB: using fread/fpassthru, the HTML5 video element, and a direct link do not work in any browser. For MP4s that are less than that amount, all those methods work.

Any of my MP4s work if I use the file URI scheme (i.e. - file://), so it doesn't seem to be an encoding error on the part of the files.

Comment: can u change the max_execution_time to 300 or 600 (10 minutes).

Comment: There doesn't appear to be enough information to answer this question right now.  Please provide additional information as requested by other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, doesn't the *php.ini* file set limits to what can be done through XAMPP, I remebered to add larger `.sql` files to my database, I had to change my `.ini` file.